# How to configure Redmine mail delivery retry times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

It looks like Redmine will retry if it failed to send an email:

```
...
Unable to deliver to domain for 60 hours.
Will continue trying for 48 hours.
No action is required on your part.
...
```

How can I configure the Redmine to disable the retrying or set the retry times ?

I'm on Redmine v2.3.2, Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and Rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Redmine which is trying to resend the email. Instead, Redmine delivers the email to an intermediate mail server (MTA) (this is the one you configure in your `configuration.yml`). If this first transfer doesn't succeed, the mail will not be redelivered at all but will either be dropped or reported to the user as an error after the update (depending on your configuration in Redmine).

After the intermediate MTA has received the mail, it will then start to deliver it to the final destination. This is the step that seems to have not succeed here, as your MTA tries to resend the mail. as this also doesn't seem to work, it send periodical notifications to the sender address.

As such, you have to configure your MTA to define how long and how often it tries to resend the mail, not Redmine.

Answer (score 2):

Redmine is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) not a mail server. In a rails app, you would typically use  [action mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to deliver emails from your application to an [SMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), which in turn is responsible to transmit them to the specified address. The message you are getting comes from the SMTP server not redmine.